# Service Broker configuration

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, service-broker

I have configured Service Broker communication between two SQL Server 2008 instances using Windows authentication. I am sending a message from Initiator Service to Target Service and then ending the conversation in the target. Since target is not sending a reply message back to initiator, does the Target Instance need to have any Route configured for sending system generated acknowledgement messages to Initiator? Can I only rely on conversation handle in Target instance to communicate back to Initiator?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A route is always needed in both directions. Even if you never send messages *explicitly* from the target, the target still needs to send *implicit* acknowledgements for each message received.

But in your case you *are* sending an explicit message: `END CONVERSATION` sends an `http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/EndDialog` message.

Comment: Good insight on the EndDialog message being sent.

Comment: Thanks Remus...I have defined the route in the target.            CREATE ROUTE [InitiatorServiceRoute]   AUTHORIZATION [dbo]   WITH  SERVICE_NAME  = N'InitiatorService' ,BROKER_INSTANCE  = N'093A3836-F45C-43D6-915C-A347BEFEC2D8'  ADDRESS  = N'TCP://192.168.49.23:7000'. Is the broker instance identifier optional? The reason is to simply the build process for deploying databases. Since now there is a cyclic dependency on Initiator and Target database for their service broker identifier information, it is making our build process complicated.

Comment: The broker instance is optional. Is only needed if you have scale-out deployment scenarios with many DBs hosting the same service and SSB needing to distinguish *which* one host a particular session. It is a better practice to omit the broker instance from the route unless *explicitly* needed (you don't need it).

Comment: See example 5 in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166090%28v=sql.105%29.aspx for when broker instance is needed.